# Calculate overall score

Tags: php, mysqli, triggers

I have a database with these tables

```
users(name, team_id, overall_user_score)
teams(id, name, team_score, totalscore)
```

How would I make a trigger to run after each update where its takes the score of all users in a team and the `team_score` of that team and add them together and puts it into `totalscore`.

I dont have any code for a trigger . I have the php to show the overall score and thats about it .

```
function showTeamScore() {
    require "connect.php";

    $score = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * 
FROM teams 
WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'")  or die(mysqli_error($connection));

  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($score)) {

 echo $data['overall_score'];
  }

}
```

Edit : Code and Problem update

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE teams SET totalscore=overall_score+IFNULL((SELECT sum(overall_user_score) FROM users WHERE team_id=id),0)") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your current query?

Comment: @MHakvoort i dont have any code for a tigger

Comment: Maybe you don't need a trigger but you can do the same with a suitable view?

Comment: @cars10 Would a trigger not be easier

Comment: A trigger would try and keep a redundant table up-to-date and bears the danger of making (all other) users wait while it does its business. Views are inobtrusive and will only "look" at up-to-date original data and combine them whenever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple subquery might do the trick:

```
-- query #1
SELECT id, tname,
   (SELECT sum(uscore) FROM usr WHERE tid=id) tscore
FROM teams ORDER BY id
```

You can either run this select directly or define a view for it.

If you *just*  want the total score you can simply do:

```
-- query #2
SELECT SUM(uscore) total_score FROM usr
```

Or, in combination with the previous team-list:

```
-- query #3 (combination of #1 and #2)
SELECT id, tname,(SELECT sum(uscore) FROM usr WHERE tid=id) tscore
FROM teams
UNION ALL
SELECT 999,'total score all teams',SUM(uscore) FROM usr
ORDER BY id
```

With sample data like - **Demo**, see here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ba5b/4

teams:

```
id  tname
1   Dallas
2   Houston
3   Austin
```

usr:

```
uid  name   tid  uscore
1    Paul   1     10
2    Mary   1      3
3   Harry   2      7
4   Frank   2      4
5   Lisa    1      15
```

You would get this result from query #3:

```
id  tname                 tscore 
1   Dallas                28
2   Houston               11
3   Austin
999 total score all teams 39
```

OK, if you want to see all users with their respective team score in the last column you can do

```
-- query #4
SELECT uid, name,uscore,(SELECT sum(uscore) FROM usr WHERE tid=u.tid) tuscore
FROM usr u
```

which will result in

```
uid  name uscore  tuscore
1    Paul    10    28
2    Mary     3    28
3    Harry    7    11
4    Frank    4    11
5    Lisa    15    28
```

**completely new answer:**

You will probably need an `update` like this one (choose #4a or #4b):

```
-- query #4a
UPDATE teams t INNER JOIN
(SELECT tid, SUM(uscore) usc FROM usr GROUP BY tid) u ON u.tid=t.id
SET t.tsc=t.tsc+u.usc
```

or (see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/040b2/1 ) :

```
-- query #4b (alternative version)
UPDATE teams SET tsc=tsc+IFNULL((SELECT sum(uscore) FROM usr WHERE tid=id),0)
-- IFNULL avoids the result to become NULL if there are no new contributions
```

Where the individual user contributions `uscore` will be added to the team total score `tsc`. It makes sense to have only *one* score column in teams.

With previous scores of

```
id  tname   tsc
1   Dallas  20
2   Houston  7
3   Austin  18
```

and the above listed user contributions the new total team scores will then be

```
id   tname   tsc
 1   Dallas   48
 2   Houston  18
 3   Austin   18
```

After that the user scores should be reset to avoid a double counting. Do

```
UPDATE usr SET uscore=0
```

(Alternatively you could set an "invalidation-flag" in the user table, if you still want to be able to *see* the last score but not count it again.)

Comment: this just adds up the user score . How do I add overall_score from teams to tscore. Also this duplicates the same score 4 times if if put the team id to 1 (because there are 4 teams ?)

Comment: could you explain the bottom query . To me it looks like the first query where it just adds up the scores from all users in a particular team

Comment: Okay , but the teams have their own score , and i would like that to be added to the sum of the users score

Comment: Well, in total I presented three queries: 1. scores per team, 2. total score over all teams, 3. (combination of 1 and 2) team scores and total score as last line.

Comment: You did , but my original question asked for " score of all users in a team and the team_score of that team and add them together and puts it into totalscore"

Comment: Now, the "total score" .. Do you want that to be `28+11=39` (my query #2) or `28+28+11+11+28=106´ (".. and add them together and puts it into totalscore") ?

Comment: thats still not right . My teams have their own scores and the users who are in that team add their scores to the teams score to get an overall team score

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but it illustrates the need of an http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE. We could have saved ourselves a lot of time with a bit more background information about your tables. OK, considering your latest information: what you need is an `UPDATE` that accumulates the team scores from user contibutions and the team scores need to be kept in table `teams` - *not* in the user table.

Comment: I can use the second query to get the accumulated score and say UPDATE teams
SET totalscore=total_score + team_score ?

Comment: Just one quick question , im using query 4b . I have 4 teams . The code updates the score for team one and then gives inaccurate scores for the rest of the teams

Comment: I have added an image to show the problem along with the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82611/discussion-between-jess-and-cars10).